# Conditionals on one numpy array while iterating over a second numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, for-loop, iteration

I read through the numpy documentation, especially as it pertains to iterating over ndarrays in a for loop. Read through suggested similar S.O. posts, but I'm still failing to solve what seems to be a relatively straight-forward problem.

I'd like to incorporate conditionals based on values of one ndarray while iterating over a different ndarray, element-wise.  Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
array1 = np.array([10,20,30,40,50])
array2 = np.array([-1,-1,1,0,1])
for x in np.nditer(array1,flags=['refs_ok']):
    if array2[x] < 0:
       #code-block here executing several tasks
```

I get the following error in reference to the if statement: "IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 5".

The code block must be executed in a time-series manner, thus the for-loop. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: `nditer` is not for beginners.  Use plain Python loops (i in range...) if you must iterate.

Comment: good suggestion thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why you're currently getting an `IndexError` with `np.nditer` is because that function is iterating over the *items* in `array1` rather than the *indices*. Since the first item is `10`, you're trying to access `array2[10]`.

The *fast* way to do this is to use conditional indexing, rather than a `for` loop. For example, if you wanted to apply some function `f` to `array1` for places where `array2` is less than 0 and another function `g` for all other places, assuming `f` and `g` are written to take in and return numpy arrays, you would write

```
array1[array2 < 0] = f(array1[array2 < 0])
array1[array2 >= 0] = g(array1[array2 >= 0])
```

This will run much faster than using a `for` loop, because the iteration happens at the C level instead of in Python. You can write pretty much any set of element-wise operations using this form without needing `for` loops.

Comment: Ah yes of course - should've seen that myself.  Great suggestion re: conditional indexing Jeremy. Thanks again.

Comment: the following also seems to work:
for idx, x in enumerate(array1):
    if array2[idx] < 0:
       #execute code-block

Comment: Yes, that will work! If you ever plan to work with large arrays (or especially multi-dimensional arrays), though, I strongly recommend conditional indexing. It's both clearer to read and faster to execute. If I've answered your question, please mark it as answered! And if not, let me know what's missing.